# Unstack MultiIndex data frame

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I am writting a test case with this multi-index data frame but I am unable to unstack. The following function produces exactly the layout I am reading from an excel file just this like this sample: [Sample file](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/ea64ba2ede55f97949e37d78d10e499420190808094138/db4903)

```
def mocked_df():
    people = ['USER 1', 'USER 2', 'USER 3',
              'USER 4', 'USER 5', 'USER 6']
    flag_and_states = [['A', 'B'], ['AL', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO']]

    # Building multi-index frame
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([people])
    columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(flag_and_states, names=['Flag', 'Name'])
    data = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

    # Return data frame with multi-index
    return pd.DataFrame(
        columns=columns,
        index=index,
        data=data
    )
```

After this I am trying to unstack the data frame:

```
df = mocked_df()
df = df.unstack().reset_index()
```

But I have the following error:

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Any ideas? The same unstack call works when used on the sample Excel file also.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is problem one level `MultiIndex` in index, so `unstack` failed with very weird errors.

```
print (df.index.nlevels)
1
#correct 2 level MultiIndex in columns
print (df.columns.nlevels)
2

print (df.index)
MultiIndex([('USER 1',),
            ('USER 2',),
            ('USER 3',),
            ('USER 4',),
            ('USER 5',),
            ('USER 6',)],
           )

#correct 2 level MultiIndex in columns
print (df.columns)
MultiIndex([('A', 'AL'),
            ('A', 'AR'),
            ('A', 'CA'),
            ('A', 'CO'),
            ('B', 'AL'),
            ('B', 'AR'),
            ('B', 'CA'),
            ('B', 'CO')],
           names=['Flag', 'Name'])
```

Solution is create index by list only `index = people`, because in index is no `MultiIndex`:

```
def mocked_df():
    people = ['USER 1', 'USER 2', 'USER 3',
              'USER 4', 'USER 5', 'USER 6']
    flag_and_states = [['A', 'B'], ['AL', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO']]

    # Building multi-index frame
    index = people
    columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(flag_and_states, names=['Flag', 'Name'])
    data = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

    # Return data frame with multi-index
    return pd.DataFrame(
        columns=columns,
        index=index,
        data=data
    )
```

Then `unstack` working correctly:

```
df = mocked_df()
df = df.unstack().reset_index()
print (df.head(10))
  Flag Name level_2  0
0    A   AL  USER 1  1
1    A   AL  USER 2  0
2    A   AL  USER 3  0
3    A   AL  USER 4  0
4    A   AL  USER 5  0
5    A   AL  USER 6  0
6    A   AR  USER 1  0
7    A   AR  USER 2  0
8    A   AR  USER 3  0
9    A   AR  USER 4  0
```

Comment: Man super thanks, you're on fire! The only "problem" here is that I want to simulate exactly the same layout as the sample file. When loading the sample file and running: "df = df.unstack().reset_index()" I can unstack without any problem. If after the function I posted I run "df.stack()", than data frame doesn't have the same layout . I'm just trying to write a test case for this that's why mocked_df() needs to return the same as reading this sample file. Is there any way to do this? Super thanks!

Comment: @brenoriba - Edited answer with solution.

Comment: EXACTLY what I need! Thank you so much buddy!

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide with a desired output, what about if you try:

```
df = df.stack().reset_index()
```